# Using Topic Models in R

Tags: machine-learning, r, text-mining, topic-model

I am learning about Probabilistic Topic Models by reading this [article](http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~blei/papers/Blei2012.pdf) by D. Blei, watching this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zeX8ZSG5uGE), and doing this exercise [A Gentle Introduction to Topic Modeling](https://eight2late.wordpress.com/2015/09/29/a-gentle-introduction-to-topic-modeling-using-r/) in R.

After the topics in my corpus are defined (by the algorithm), will the "LDA" package in R allow me to find the documents for a specific topic that was modeled? Put differently, how can I check which documents contributed to the formation of a certain topic in the final model?

Any advice on this topic or how to better formulate my question is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In the R code under the link for  [A Gentle Introduction to Topic Modeling](https://eight2late.wordpress.com/2015/09/29/a-gentle-introduction-to-topic-modeling-using-r/) there is a snippet that does just what I'm looking for - i.e. it attributes each document in the corpus to one of 5 theme topics.

```
#write out results
#docs to topics
ldaOut.topics <- as.matrix(topics(ldaOut))
write.csv(ldaOut.topics,file=paste("LDAGibbs",k,"DocsToTopics.csv"))
```

This snippet quantifies the probability with which each document is associated with a certain theme:

```
#probabilities associated with each topic assignment
topicProbabilities <- as.data.frame(ldaOut@gamma)
write.csv(topicProbabilities,file=paste("LDAGibbs",k,"TopicProbabilities.csv"))
```

Comment: Note that topic model attributes a stochastic mixture of the topics to each document, not _one_ topic.